# Reemplazar asteriscos por números PYTHON

Tags: python

Quisiera saber cómo podría dada una string reemplazar todos los asteriscos que aparezcan en ella por números sucesivos, es decir, si tenemos 3 asteriscos, que se sustituya el primero por un 1, el segundo por un 2 y el tercero por un 3.

Ejemplo:

```
sust_ast('En * día cumpliré ** años')
>>>>>> 'En 1 día cumpliré 23 años'
sust_ast('Pasaron ********** años')
>>>>> 'Pasaron 12345678910 años'
```

Código: (estoy empezando a programar, disculpen)

```
def asteriscos(s): 
    count=0
    for letra in s:
        if letra=='*':
            count+=1
            s = s.replace(letra,str(count))           
    return s
```

No logro entender por qué no funciona :(

Comment: Nosotros no haremos ese ejercicio por ti. Podrias agregar el codigo que lograste hacer hasta ahora por favor (incluso si no funciona)?

Comment: Ahí lo teneis ;) . Estoy comenzando a programar, disculpen el nivel.

Comment: El método `str.replace()` te está reemplazando todos los asterísticos por `1`s, que es el primer número del bucle for. Puedes hacer que sólo te modifique un asterísco pasando el argumento `count=1` al método  `str.replace()` ([documentación de str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?str.replace#str.replace))

Answer (score 0):

La forma más sencilla que pude pensar es armar un nuevo string e ir agregando el caracter que corresponda a medida que encuentre letras o *

```
def asteriscos(s): 
    count=0
    nuevoString = ""
    for letra in s:
        if letra=='*':
            count+=1
            nuevoString+=str(count)
        else:
            nuevoString+=letra
    return nuevoString
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en este [enlace](https://replit.com/@marcelozarate/UtilizedWastefulComputing#main.py)

Answer (score 0):

El motivo por el cual no funciona es que estás remplazando todos los asteriscos `*` por `1` en la primera iteración, quedando así: `Pasaron 1111111111 años`, el resto de las iteraciones se salta la condición que busca asteriscos porque no los hay.

Lo que deseas es remplazar caracteres según su ubicación o indice, como siguiere en [esta otra respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41753038/13636459) puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```py
index=s.find('*')
s = s[:index]+str(count)+s[index+1:]
```

Aun así no es recomendable cambiar la lista sobre la cual se itera dentro del `for-loop`.

Salida: `En 1 día cumpliré 23 años` ,`Pasaron 12345678910 años`